# Picture alignment with Isotope and imagesLoaded

Tags: jquery, html, alignment, jquery-isotope

I wanna load some flickr photos from a company account and have some problems with the alignment of the pictures.

I'm using Isotope to align the pictures in a proper manner. Now I'm facing the problem, that the pictures overlap when my site loads the first time. When I resize the window, the pictures alignment is working and everything is fine, but it doesn't solve my basic problem.
To fix the overlapping problem for the first call on the site, I tried to use the recommended imagesloaded.js but its not working.

First I thought it's because I loaded the pictures via an asynchronous ajax call, so I changed my AJAX function to the following function but I'm still facing the same problem.

```
$.getJSON("https://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?id=125591374@N02&format=json&jsoncallback=?", function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    $("img").each(function () {
        $(this).attr("src", data.items[i].media.m);
        i++;
    });
});
```

Here is my Isotope script

```
var $container = $('#picContainer');

$container.isotope({
    itemSelector: '.picContainer-item'
    , percentPosition: true
    , layoutMode: 'masonry'
    , masonry: {
        columnWidth: 50
    }
});

$container.imagesLoaded().progress(function () {
    $container.isotope("layout");
});
```

I can't find the problem. Does anyone know where did I something wrong?

I also prepared a codepen for a better understanding :)

[Codepen example](http://codepen.io/tobi_86/pen/KMdYdB)

Thanks!

Comment: Problem solves, just placing the imagesLoaded() function further up

Comment: Not solved. That disables the Isotope library itself. Try resizing the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's happening is isotope is being loaded before all of your images are. So it's not setting the correct width until it renders it again (when you resize the window). If you place your isotope code inside a `$(window).load(function(){})` (which runs only after all resources have been loaded), it will work.

```
$(window).load(function() {

  var $container = $('#picContainer');

    $container.isotope({
      itemSelector: '.picContainer-item'
      , percentPosition: true
      , layoutMode: 'masonry'
      , masonry: {
        columnWidth: 50
      }
    });

});
```

[**CodePen**](http://codepen.io/Hunter377/pen/beVyNz)

(Also, you can remove the imagesloaded.js)

Comment: Im sorry, i was a bit to fast with my answer. It doesn't work like u said. I placed the isotope function inside the json call but it' still the same problem. The pictures are more overlapping like before now

Comment: Okay, I think there's some kind of caching issue, it was working before. Let me work on it a little more.

Comment: Yes i did and if i load it straight from my normal browser, i do have the problem like i said. If i use the incognito modus of chrome, everything is working fine. Seems like a caching problem with my browser. Many thanks for the solution.

Comment: No, I'm pretty sure it's still broken, haha. I just solved it. You need a window.load over the isotope function. Let me update my answer.

Comment: Yes you are right. I guess the window.load function is the better programming style than the setTimeout function.

Comment: Yes, it's much better. Because if you're request takes longer than expected, then it will load too soon and mess up your code. And if your request loads quickly, then you'd have to wait on the timeout. `Window.load` will only run after your resources are loaded.